# Getting skip, offset, total info of an aggregation's result with MongoDB driver for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

in our application we used to query data with coll.find() method and it returned Cursor instance from which I could retrieve all the data needed for the client.

```
const coll: Collection = await this.ensureCollection(collection);

let query = { ... };

let result: Cursor = await coll.find(query);

let total: Cursor = await coll.count(query);

let readResult = {
    offset: result.cursorState.skip,
    limit:  result.cursorState.currentLimit,
    total,
    data: result.toArray();
}
```

I'm trying to move it to aggregation for our new filter system.

```
const coll: Collection = await this.ensureCollection(collection);

let query = [{ $skip: ... }, { $limit: ... }];

let result = await coll.aggregate(query);

let limit: number;
let offset: number;

let limitPipeline: any = aggregationQuery.find(pipeline => (typeof pipeline.$limit !== 'undefined'));

if (limitPipeline) {
    limit = limitPipeline.$limit;
}

let offsetPipeline: any = aggregationQuery.find(pipeline => (typeof pipeline.$skip !== 'undefined'));

if (offsetPipeline) {
    offset = offsetPipeline.$skip;
}

let total: number = ???

let readResult = {
    offset,
    limit,
    total,
    data: result.toArray();
}
```

**Questions:**

1) How do I get limit and offset properly? The way I get limit and offset isn't safe. The way I retrieved them when I was using coll.find() method doesn't not work with aggregation.

2) How do I get total amount of documents my query returns?

I'd like to know how it's done in real applications, best practices.
Thanks.

Comment: result.count() or result.toArray().length, since you do result.toArray() anyway.

Comment: @AlexBlex It's not gonna work since I'm using limit,  the result array will be just a limited amount of documents but not the total amount of them.

Comment: Then you need to make a second request replacing skip-limit with group-count, or apply skip-limit to the cursor, as you did with find.